# How to bind properties of ListBox in code behind file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple listbox that shows a couple of items.

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    public Person SelectedPerson { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Mark", Age = 20 });
        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 25 });

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click_ShowSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I have this binding in XAML which works but I want to do the same in code behind file. How do I do that?

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding Person}"/>
    <Button Content="Show Selected" Click="Button_Click_ShowSelected"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is what I have tried but the parameters of `Binding` class are confusing and this doesn't work.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Mark", Age = 20 });
        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 25 });

        DataContext = this;

        Binding binding1 = new Binding();
        binding1.Source = People;
        listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding1);

        Binding binding2 = new Binding("Name");
        binding2.Source = People; // or null since this property builds on ItemSource?
        listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, binding2);

        Binding binding3 = new Binding("SelectedPerson");
        binding3.Source = null;
        listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedItemProperty, binding3);
    }
```

Comment: This begs the question: why exactly do you want to do it from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be *exactly* the same as your XAML, I believe you don't set the source at all - it will default to the data context - and you just use the path in the binding instead:

```cs
Binding itemsSourceBinding = new Binding("People");
listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding);

// No binding here; it's just a simple property
listbox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";

// This is "Person" in the XAML, but I suspect that's a typo
Binding selectedItemBinding = new Binding("SelectedPerson");
listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedItemProperty, selectedItemBinding);
```

That's binding to the path instead of to specific objects - which means if you raised item changed notifications for `People` or `SelectedPerson`, the UI could react to it. That's almost certainly what you want to do for `SelectedPerson`; for `People`, if you never change the property to a different collection, but you just modify that existing collection, I suspect you *could* use a binding with a `Source` of `People`... but I'd probably stick with the form above anyway.